# Spark: how to read orc file into RDD format not dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I get a series of `orc` files whose size is more than **1T**.
And if use to read it into DataFrame format which will cause oom.

So I am wondering if there is a way to read data into RDD format, not DataFrame format.

Spark configuration:

```
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=50
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=100
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should be able to read more than 1TB using dataframe. Can you share your code, clusters specs, and Spark configurations?

Comment: And how did you read the orc files? with `spark.sql` or `spark.read`?